# Filter groups by occurrence of multiple values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825037/filter-groups-by-occurrence-of-a-value) but with an added wrinkle.  I'd like to filter only groups of rows that have both of two (or all of several) values in a particular column in any row of the group.

For example, say I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Group=LETTERS[c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)], Value=c(5, 1:4, 1:4, 5))
```

And I want those letters where any letter has both a row with a corresponding value of 4 AND a row with a corresponding value of 5, so this:

```
  Group Value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 C         2
2 C         3
3 C         4
4 C         5
```

I can do that with a pair of `any` calls inside `filter` like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(any(Value == 4),
         any(Value == 5))
```

Is there a way to do the filter call in one line?  Something like: (note **this doesn't work**, `all_of` is not a real function)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(all_of(Value == 4 & Value == 5))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`all` is a valid function and can be used in combination with `%in%` (for vectors of length >=1)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>%
    filter(all(c(4, 5) %in% Value))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Group [1]
#  Group Value
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 C         2
#2 C         3
#3 C         4
#4 C         5
```

---

Or with `sum` of logical vector

```
df %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    filter(!sum(!c(4, 5) %in% Value))
```