# In R, conditionally subset unique IDs using a NONE or NEVER condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

**Background**

I've got a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b", "c","c"),
                event = c(0,1,0,0,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2015-07-12")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's got some people (`ID`), a binary indicator of an `event`, and an `event_date` for that `event`.

**The Problem**

I want to subset this dataframe to return the rows for those ID's who have **never** had the event -- in other words, for ID's whose every `event` cell, no matter how many they have, equals zero. No exceptions.

In other words, I'd like to get something that looks like this:

```
ID event event_date
 b     0 2011-12-23
 b     0 2011-12-31
```

**What I've tried**

I've got a couple of ways of trying to do this, one in `dplyr` and the other in `data.table` (I'm more familiar with `dplyr`; the latter example is adapted from an answer to an older question I posted). But both get me the same result: the inclusion of ID=`b`, which is good, but also the inclusion of ID=`a`, who has one row of `event`=1 -- which is not good.

Attempt 1:

```
d_test <- subset(d, ID %in% unique(ID[event == 0])) %>% 
  arrange(ID, event_date)

  ID event event_date
1  a     0 2011-01-01
2  a     1 2012-08-21
3  b     0 2011-12-23
4  b     0 2011-12-31
```

Attempt 2:

```
setDT(d)
d_test <- d[ID %in% d[,event==0, by=ID][V1==TRUE, ID]]

   ID event event_date
1:  a     0 2011-01-01
2:  a     1 2012-08-21
3:  b     0 2011-12-23
4:  b     0 2011-12-31
```

Bottom line: I can't express NEVER or NONE in my code.

Comment: `subset(d, ave(as.logical(event), ID, FUN = Negate(any)))` or `subset(d, ave(event, ID, FUN = sum) == 0)`.

Comment: Think I've answered this before, but `d[, if (all(event == 0)) .SD, by=ID]` . Essentially the same `if` logic here allowing the dropping of groups meeting a criteria - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302610/remove-ids-that-occur-x-times-r/18304851

Comment: On further reflection, `all` and `any` may be what you're essentially looking to know about. Negating `any` (`!any(...)` or `Negate(any)(...)`) is then a `none` essentially. So maybe a better duplicate might also be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825037/select-groups-which-have-at-least-one-of-a-certain-value if you make the edit to change `any(...)` to one of the above.

Comment: `subset(d, ave(!event, ID, FUN = all))` or even `subset(d, !ave(event, ID, FUN = sum))`

Comment: Thank you everyone for these answers. They all work on my toy `df` used here; I'm running them now on my real-world dataset to see how they apply to a few million rows and ~30 columns. It seems like my question may be a duplicate; I'm fine if that's the case. If not, please feel free to write up your answers as proper answers and I'll mark them correct.

Comment: With `dplyr`, `d |> group_by(ID) |> filter(...)` where `...` could be (a) `!any(event == 1)`, (b) `all(event != 1)` (c) `! 1 %in% event`, (d) `sum(event) == 0` (since it's binary), (e) `sum(event == 1) == 0`, (f) simplifying (a) since it's binary `!any(event)`, (g) codegolfing (b) since it's binary `all(!event)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table` and `any` to create a column to indicate if ID has at least one event :

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(ID = c("a","a","b","b", "c","c"),
                event = c(0,1,0,0,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2015-07-12")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d[, any.event := any(event == 1), by = "ID"]

   ID event event_date any.event
1:  a     0 2011-01-01      TRUE
2:  a     1 2012-08-21      TRUE
3:  b     0 2011-12-23     FALSE
4:  b     0 2011-12-31     FALSE
5:  c     1 2013-03-14      TRUE
6:  c     1 2015-07-12      TRUE
```

`any` checks if the condition is fulfilled for at least one element of event. `by` applies this function for each `ID`.

Then you can filter the data.table using column any.event :

```
d[!(any.event)]

   ID event event_date any.event
1:  b     0 2011-12-23     FALSE
2:  b     0 2011-12-31     FALSE
```